# Rearrange divs inside a main div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to rearrange the div index inside of a main Div.But it is not working as expected.

Here is my html code

```
    <div id="divAll">
    <div id="divVideo">
        Video
    </div>

    <div id="divAudio">
        Audio
    </div>

    <div id="divImage">
        Image
    </div>
</div>

<input id="btn" type="button" />
```

And here is the jQuery code

```
    function Rearrange(videoP,audioP,imageP){
    if(videoP=="1"){
        $('#divAll').prependTo('#divVideo');
    }
    else if(audioP=="1"){
        $('#divAll').prependTo('#divAudio');
    }
    else if(imageP=="1"){
        $('#divAll').prependTo('#divImage');
    }

    if(videoP=="2"){
        $('#divAll div:eq(1)').after('#divVideo');
    }
    else if(audioP=="2"){
        $('#divAll div:eq(1)').after('#divAudio');
    }
    else if(imageP=="2"){
        $('#divAll div:eq(1)').after('#divImage');
    }

    if(videoP=="3"){
        $('#divAll div:eq(2)').after('#divVideo');
    }
    else if(audioP=="3"){
        $('#divAll div:eq(2)').after('#divAudio');
    }
    else if(imageP=="3"){
        $('#divAll div:eq(2)').after('#divImage');
    }
}
$('#btn').click(function(){
Rearrange(3,2,1);
});
```

On click of the button i'm trying to change the position of the divs as per parameters to function, but its resulting in no div in the main div.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64H45/)

Comment: I'm not sure `$('#divAll').prependTo('#divVideo');` can work -- it tries to put the parent inside its child. But that means the child has to become a grandchild of itself.

Comment: Read the doc carefully : http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be one of possible solutions

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/64H45/3/)**

```
function Rearrange(videoP,audioP,imageP){  
   $('#temp').append($('#divAll div'));
    alert($('#temp').html());
    for(i=1;i<4;i++)
    {        
        if(i==videoP)
            $('#divAll').append($('#divVideo'));
        if(i==audioP)
            $('#divAll').append($('#divAudio'));
        if(i==imageP)
            $('#divAll').append($('#divImage'));
    }
}
```

**Edit**

If you can pass array of ids to decide the order you will come up with more generic solution.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/64H45/4/)**

```
function Rearrange(arrOfId){  
    $('#temp').append($('#divAll div'));    
    for(i=0;i<arrOfId.length;i++)
        $('#divAll').append($('#' + arrOfId[i]));    
}

$('#btn').click(function(){
     Rearrange(['divImage', 'divAudio','divVideo']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this problem can be easily done using this small function.
No need of any extra div.

```
function Rearrange_Div(array){  
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    $('#divAll').append($('#' + array[i]));    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this works for you.

```
function Rearrange(videoP,audioP,imageP){
 $divtemp =$('#divAll').clone().html("");
 if(videoP==audioP || audioP== imageP || videoP == imageP)
 {
     alert("access denied");
 }
 else
 {
    if(videoP=="1"){            
          $divtemp.append($("#divVideo").clone());
    }
    else if(audioP=="1"){
        $divtemp.append($("#divAudio").clone());
    }
    else if(imageP=="1"){
        $divtemp.append($("#divImage").clone());
    }

    if(videoP=="2"){
        $divtemp.append($("#divVideo").clone());
    }
    else if(audioP=="2"){
        $divtemp.append($("#divAudio").clone());
    }
    else if(imageP=="2"){
        $divtemp.append($("#divImage").clone());
    }

    if(videoP=="3"){
        $divtemp.append($("#divVideo").clone());
    }
    else if(audioP=="3"){
        $divtemp.append($("#divAudio").clone());
    }
    else if(imageP=="3"){
        $divtemp.append($("#divImage").clone());
    }
    $("#divAll").html("");
    $("#divAll").append($divtemp.html());
  }
}


$("#btn").click(function(){
Rearrange(2,3,1);
});
```

[fiddle link is here](http://jsfiddle.net/itsaddy/64H45/65/)